# Android: How to swipe between activities (not fragments), master/detail best set-up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, adt

I'm working on an android app and I'm fairly new to all this, including mobile app development, so I have a few questions. Any help would be amazing!

1) Is it possible to swipe between entire activities (including action bar)?
    And I don't mean like viewPager swapping between fragments, I mean swapping the 
    entire screen (like snapchat does on iOS). Is this possible at all? And if so, 
    how can I do this?

2) What is the best way to implement a master/detail type layout? Like twitter 
for instance, if i have a listView of the tweets, and when a person clicks on a 
tweet it takes you to a detailed view of that specific tweet... What would be the 
best way to accomplish this? Would I have an activity with a list view and create 
a second activity upon clicking on a tweet? Or would I use fragments instead, one 
for the list view and one for the detailed view?

3) Is there a way to have different action bars for every fragment?

Thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes swiping is possible:

OnTouchSwipeListener

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {



private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private Context context;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.view.View.OnTouchListener#onTouch(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)
 */
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

/**
 * Gets the gesture detector.
 * 
 * @return the gesture detector
 */
public GestureDetector getGestureDetector(){
    return  gestureDetector;
}

/**
 * Instantiates a new on swipe touch listener.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 */
public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener#onDown(android.view.MotionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent, android.view.MotionEvent, float, float)
     */

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getRawY() - e1.getRawY();
            float diffX = e2.getRawX() - e1.getRawX();
            if ((Math.abs(diffX) - Math.abs(diffY)) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return result;
    }
}

/**
 * On swipe right.
 */
public void onSwipeRight() {
}

/**
 * On swipe left.
 */
public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

/**
 * On swipe top.
 */
public void onSwipeTop() {
}

/**
 * On swipe bottom.
 */
public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
}
```

Implementation:

```
OnSwipeTouchListener onSwipeTouchListener = new OnSwipeTouchListener(Activity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            //your actions
        }
    };
```

Comment: By Activity.this I mean the naem of your activity

Comment: Is it possible to animate swiping the entire screen (including the actionBar) with fragments instead of activities?

Comment: Using the actionbar implementation,No(i've tried it,so not speaking hypothetically).If you want to swipe actionbar and the fragment,I'd suggest displaying 2 fragment containers in the main activity. viz:
Container 1:keep replacing by substituting other fragment action bars
Container 2:main fragment container

or just dont use fragments,use activity with you custom implemented bar on the top..that way when you switch activity,everything will change.

IMHO:action bars should remain same for majority of the screens or else you don not need to implement the android action bar itself,use custom

Comment: this is not working at all even it is not showing Toast onSwipe
I wrote this class and i test it on MainActivity

Answer (score 2):

```
Is it possible to swipe between entire activities (including action bar)?
```

No you cant, you can only do it with `Fragments` not with `Activities`.

```
What is the best way to implement a master/detail type layout?
```

You can use fragment and just add it to the current layout. Another solution is to create a dialog that will have layout.

```
Is there a way to have different action bars for every fragment?
```

Only activity can have `ActionBar` but you can still make your own `ActionBar` by creating it using layout and inflate it to the fragment.

Comment: This is helpful thanks. I guess a better question would be, how can snapchat for example allow for swiping from an entire screen with an action bar to another screen with a totally different action bar (both color and actions on it)?

Comment: @Gus they are using fragment for swiping with different layout on it with each specified actionbar style

Answer (score 2):

in addition to @Mirek Rusin answer

OnSwipeTouchListener.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Usage on your activity : 
define a layout (Linear or relative or anything even a toolbar or an image..)

```
yourLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MyActivity.this) {
public void onSwipeTop() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeRight() {
    startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
            finish();
}
public void onSwipeLeft() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void onSwipeBottom() {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can swipe between activities. 
Check [this library](https://github.com/gongwen/SwipeBackLayout).
Also take a look at [this link](https://medium.com/@DaniAmjad/5-most-amazing-android-libraries-13d2a720cf55)