# Drop event not detected between activities API 22+

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to give the user the ability to drag from one activity to another, within my app, but the drop event not detected

**Starting Drag operation in the First activity:**

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aParent, View aView, int aPos, long aID) {

    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(aView);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Phase", "Phase");    

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        aView.startDragAndDrop(ClipData.newIntent(DRAG_N_DROP_DESCRIPTION, intent), shadowBuilder, null, 0);
    } else {
        aView.startDrag(ClipData.newIntent(DRAG_N_DROP_DESCRIPTION, intent), shadowBuilder, null, 0);
    }


    startSecondActivity();

    finish();

    return true;
}
```

**Receiving Drop Operation in the Second activity**

```
public boolean onDrag(View aView, DragEvent aEvent) {

    switch (aEvent.getAction()) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                 This is not called on Android 22+
                 break;

          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          This is not called on Android 22+
                 break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

There will be 50 points reward for the solution.

Comment: Any suggestions or explanation?

Comment: Please refer this https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/DragAndDropAcrossApps example. You may get some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for why onDrop isn't called, perhaps this text from the developers site explains it.

> The user releases the drag shadow within the bounding box of a View
> that can accept the data. The system sends the View object's listener
> a drag event with action type ACTION_DROP. The drag event contains the
> data that was passed to the system in the call to startDrag() that
> started the operation. The listener is expected to return boolean true
> to the system if code for accepting the drop succeeds. Note that this
> step only occurs if the user drops the drag shadow within the bounding
> box of a View whose listener is registered to receive drag events. If
> the user releases the drag shadow in any other situation, no
> ACTION_DROP drag event is sent.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop

Answer (score 0):

An onSwipeTouchListener with a GestureListener may fit what you want. You forward onTouch events to the GestureListener. The onSwipeTouchListener is attached to a top level View. The OnSwipeTouchListener gets a reference to the Activity, and when swiped, the OnSwipeTouchListener calls on the Activity to Start a new Activity.

For code, see the answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48142661/13264143