# How do I make AppCompatActivity activities swipeable and include an app bar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat, android-appbarlayout, android-viewpager2

I have a total of three activities of type `AppCompatActivity`. In each activity's xml, I have the following to set up an app bar:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/black" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

I implemented this app bar to allow users to change the activity by clicking on one of the three buttons in the app bar. If the user would rather swipe through activities, I have included the following in each activity's xml:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar_layout" />
```

The problem I have right now is I can't use `ViewPager2` for `AppCompatActivity`. It can only be used for `Fragments`, but that won't work with the code I already have. How do I make my three activities that are of type `AppCompatActivity` swipeable and include an app bar in each one so users can click on buttons to go to new activities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to swipe between activities (not fragments), master/detail best set-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254722/android-how-to-swipe-between-activities-not-fragments-master-detail-best-set)

Comment: "I can't use ViewPager2 for AppCompatActivity" . Try setting a MainFragment as the main content for this activity.

Comment: "but that won't work with the code I already have" -- you should strongly consider switching your screens to be fragments.

Comment: @javdromero That doesn't answer my question. That makes my entire screen swipeable. I'm only trying to make a portion of the screen swipable.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why?

Comment: "I'm only trying to make a portion of the screen swipable." Use fragments, that's the correct answer. It would make everything else easier, the tab, toolbar, etc.

Comment: "Why?" -- first, everything is set up for what you want, if you use fragments (or views) as pages in a `ViewPager2`. Conversely, activities are not set up for that, and the suggestions in the link from the first comment, frankly, are hacks with poor UX. For example, usually, with swiping, you want to see the next page start to appear as the previous page is being swiped away -- that is impractical with activities. Also, Google has been pushing developers away from having lots of activities for a few years now.